# Disconnect incoming call on Nougat and later

Tags: android

I have a code which identifies incoming call for Android 5. Below I am providing snippet for the same.

Manifest file snippet -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

<receiver android:name=".receiver.CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver implementation as below -

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private static final String TAG = "CallReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
Log.i(TAG, "Inside onReceived : Phone state."+stateStr+" From : "+number);
}
}
```

Problem here is, I have tried to test this code on Android 5, onReceive is called & it could show me log message; but same code if I try it on Android 7 then no luck. I could notice onReceive is not called.
Is there any API specific change I must implement here ?

Answer (score -1):

In new versions of Android this is considered a dangerous permission and requires run time permissions to use.  This means that you must prompt for permission on first use, and that you cannot register for it in the manifest, you must do so at runtime.

Comment: For versions up & equal to Android 5, I am retaining AndroidManifest receiver tag. In the very first onCreate I have below snippet

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

            receiver = new CallReceiver();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"); //TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED
            this.registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

        }
Still I dont see a call to a phone is getting trapped.